# windows batch command to change directory with wildcard having conflict folder

Tags: windows, batch-file

IF we have two directories like below:

jdk160_29
jdk160_35

what is the command to change directory having highest suffix using wild card like cd jdk*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save this (untested) in a batch file.

```
cd <parent folder>
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /ad jdk*') do set folder_of_interest=%%a
cd %folder_of_interest%
```

Explanation:
Iterate over all folders named jdk*, and set folder_of_interest in each iteration. At the end, it will have the last alphabetically sorted one.